# Using decrement_counter in after_update callback is subtracting 2?

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-4, increment, counter-cache

I have three models.  Employer, User, Job.

```
 class Employers
    has_many :jobs
    has_many :users, through: :jobs
 end

 class User
    has_many :jobs
 end

 class Job
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :employer
 end
```

The Job model has a boolean column named "current".  An employers user count is derived by counting all the associated jobs marked 'current'.

I opted to rolled my own cache counter, rather than use active records.

Im using a before filter in the Job model to either increment or decrement a users_count in the Employer model.  The increment works as expected, but no matter how I tweak the code...the decrement drops the count by a value of 2.

Im sure I can clean these methods up a bit...there might be some redundancy.

## 1 Why is the decrement subtracting 2 instead of 1?

## 2 Can the active record cache counter handle logic like this?

```
class Job

    before_destroy :change_employer_users_counter_cache_after_destroy
    before_create :change_employer_users_counter_cache_after_create
    before_update :change_employer_users_counter_cache_after_update


    def change_employer_users_counter_cache_after_create
       Operator.increment_counter(:users_count, self.operator_id) if self.current == true
    end

    def change_employer_users_counter_cache_after_update
       if self.current_changed?
          if self.current == true
            Operator.increment_counter(:users_count, self.operator_id)
          else
            Operator.decrement_counter(:users_count, self.operator_id)
          end
       end
    end  

    def change_employer_users_counter_cache_after_destroy
       Operator.decrement_counter(:users_count, self.operator_id)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

the gem "counter_culture" handled this very nicely...and cleaned up my code.